# React Native Pressable onPressIn only called when OnPress handler is present

Tags: react-native, event-handling, pressable

In the android emulator, the following RN code does nothing (no log, no handler called)

```
<Pressable style={[styles.fullscreenContainer]}  
  onPressIn={()=> {console.log("onPress");this.props.touchHandler()}}>
```

However, if I insert a `onPress` handler, in otherwise exactly the same code, both logs appear and both handlers are called when the component is pressed.

```
<Pressable style={[styles.fullscreenContainer]}  
  onPress=  {()=> {console.log("onPress");  this.props.touchHandler()}} 
  onPressIn={()=> {console.log("onPressIn");this.props.touchHandler()}}>
```

Why does `onPressIn` not work on its own?

FYI `onPressIn` works correctly on iOS in the expo client

Answer (score 0):

`onPressIn` is followed by `onPress`, but if you haven't given `onPress` any logic to perform, then nothing will happen. You'll only get an `onPressIn` response, even though `onPress` is technically still triggered behind the scenes. (It's just a blank `onPress`).